# TAutoComplete Class for C++Builder?

Tags: c++builder

Where can someone download a `TAutoComplete` class for C++Builder (or how do you create one)?  I would like to add support for `IAutoComplete2` to a `TButtonedEdit` field in C++Builder.

Or does C++Builder have a history component for Edit type fields built-in?

TIA!!

Comment: "*how do you create one?*" - On my website is an article that I wrote many years ago for BCBJ about using `IAutoComplete` in C++Builder: [Using Microsoft’s Auto-Completion Framework](http://www.lebeausoftware.org/articles/bcbj_vol10_num9.1.pdf).  Should be trivial to expand on it for `IAutoComplete2`. "*does C++Builder have a history component for Edit type fields built-in?*" - no, it does not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's great, is the source available for download?

Comment: Unfortunately, BCBJ no longer exists, and I believe the source code for its articles has been lost to time :*-( Unless you can find an archive/CD somewhere (archive.org has a copy of the BCBJ site, but not the files for its source code). I didn't think to grab the source code when I saved my articles. Shouldn't be too hard to reproduce the code based on the info in the article, though.